# How to add additional data to object Auth in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

There is default object `Auth` in Laravel after authification.

It contents data about current user from table Users.
How can I add the additional data to this object from other related table?

**Edit:**
So, if I am right, the object Auth is created when user is authenticated. In this moment I need to fill object by additional data.

Comment: I'm looking to do the same, did you ever get this figured out? I have the data from the user table, which is already getting selected during Auth, and data in a settings table that I also need at login.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you want to retrieve a user in a controller and return it as a response, maybe json? or not, it's doesn't really matter. here what you could do

```
public function getUser()
{
     $user = auth()->user();

     $user->load('relationName');
     $user->load('anotherRelationName');
}
```

Comment: Yes, but where I can change this? In what file?

Comment: you would to this in a controller, or some other class that is responsible for fetching data for your user. Update your question by providing some code so I have better understanding. or at least tell a bit more what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I mean where is formed Auth object with data from user model?